# J2ME - How to copy area into Image in Canvas?

Tags: java-me

I want to copy any area in Canvas with x and y coordinates and then paste it to any Image.

In example:

```
Image image = Image.createImage(30, 20);
image.drawImage(canvas);
```

Comment: This could work: `canvas.paint(image.getGraphics());`, with some clipping stuff if you need only some are...

Comment: I think you misunderstand Ales. He wants to copy an area from the Canvas and paste it into an Image. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to copy data from `Canvas` nor `GameCanvas`.

To achieve what you want, you have to use doublebuffering. Meaning, you have to use an `Image bufferImg` as your buffer to draw on, and then draw that `bufferImg` onto your `Canvas`.

That way, you can copy from the `Image` onto another `Image` like this:

```
bufferImg.getRGB(int[] rgbData, int offset, int scanlength, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

and then

```
g.drawRGB(int[] rgbData, int offset, int scanlength, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean processAlpha);
```

where `g` is the `Graphics` object of the 2nd `Image` you want to draw onto.

Using a doublebuffer like this will slow things down a bit on some devices of course, but you can't do it any other way if you want to be able to "extract" portions of the screen.